# How to make a dictionary from two nested list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two nested lists:

```
list1 = [['s0'], ['s1'], ['s2']]
list2 = [['hello','world','the'],['as','per','the'],['assets','order']]
```

and I want to make a dictionary from these lists with keys from `list1` and values from `list2`:

```
d = {s0:['hello','world','the'],s1:['as','per','the'],s2:['assets','order']}
```

The output should look like this:

```
d = {s0:['hello','world','the'],s1:['as','per','the'],s2:['assets','order']}
```

The following code works if `list1` is a normal (non-nested) list. But it doesn't work when `list1` is a nested list.

```
dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the edits. This was my first question so the format was not proper. Thanks a lot for making it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange way to store matching information in the first place, but I would combine them like this:

```
list1 = [['s0'], ['s1'], ['s2']]
list2 = [['hello','world','the'],['as','per','the'],['assets','order']]

assert(len(list1) == len(list2))
output_dict = dict()
for index in range(len(list1)):
    output_dict[list1[index][0] = list2[index]
```

result:

```
{'s0': ['hello', 'world', 'the'], 's1': ['as', 'per', 'the'], 's2': ['assets', 'order']}
```

I am assuming that the variables s0, s1 and s2 are meant to be strings like in the first list.

Comment: thank yo for the help and I know its strange, but I made this lists from xml files and its gets further weird as I need to combine this type of many dictionaries to make a new dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that lists are *not hashable*, so one thing you can do is to flatten your list with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and then build the dictionary with strings (which *are* immutable) as keys following you're current approach (read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for a more detailed explanation on this topic):

```
from itertools import chain

dict(zip(chain.from_iterable(list1),list2))

{'s0': ['hello', 'world', 'the'],
 's1': ['as', 'per', 'the'],
 's2': ['assets', 'order']}
```

Comment: The important thing is, that `list1`  is a list of lists!

Comment: Yes, that's why I mention that lists are not hashable @OcasoProtal :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. And yes when I used dict(zip(list1, list2)) the error was that lists are not hashable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it manually (to understand algorithm for exemple), here is a way to do so:

```
list1 = [['s0'], ['s1'], ['s2']]
list2 = [['hello','world','the'],['as','per','the'],['assets','order']]

if len(list1) != len(list2):
    exit(-1)

res = {}
for index, content in enumerate(list1):
    res[content[0]] = list2[index]

print(res)
```

Comment: I would pattern-match on `content` since there's only one element in the list: `for index, [content] in enumerate(list1):`. But your way works equally fine. :)

Comment: Just a matter of coding-style

Answer (score 2):

Another answer could be :

```
list1 = [['s0'], ['s1'], ['s2']]
list2 = [['hello','world','the'],['as','per','the'],['assets','order']]
output_dict = {element1[0]: element2 for element1, element2 in zip(list1, list2)}
```

An similar way of this dict-comprehension :

```
output_dict = {element1: element2 for [element1], element2 in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Output :

```
{'s0': ['hello', 'world', 'the'],
 's1': ['as', 'per', 'the'],
 's2': ['assets', 'order']}
```